# Firebase transaction doesn't abort remotely if previously committed locally

Tags: android, transactions, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Android app in which several users can access, modify and delete the same item and I'm using Firebase to sync all the devices.
In order to keep track of the updates the item has a timestamp.
I wrote a transaction so that when I try to delete the item it checks if the timestamp of my copy is older than the remote copy: in that case the transaction aborts and the item is not deleted.

Here my problem:

1. My device goes offline
2. I successfully delete the item
3. Another user modifies the item on the remote database
4. My device goes online and propagates his deletion

I thought it would have aborted remotely as the remote timestamp is newer.
I really can't see the point of the abort function if I can only abort basing the decision on my local data...

How should I handle these kinds of conflicts in Firebase?

-- UPDATE

This is the code I use to remove an item. It should abort if another user has changed the item remotely after the deletion has happened locally.

```
private void removeItem(final ListItem item, final Firebase itemRef) {
    itemRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if(mutableData == null) return Transaction.abort();
            else if((long)mutableData.child("lastUpdate").getValue() > item.getLastUpdate()) return Transaction.abort();
            else{
                itemRef.removeValue();
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
        }
    });
```

Please note I use `itemRef.removeValue()` instead of `mutableData.setValue(null)` because the second one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work the way you expect it to work, show the code please. I have an idea what you can do to fix your problem, so will provide an answer based on that. But it would be a lot easier to be certain if you'd show code, which is why I also voted to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

1. I used `mutableData.setValue(null)`, otherwise Firebase can't make the transaction work properly
2. I set the `applyLocally`boolean explicitly to true as I need to see local events too

I don't understand why `mutableData.setValue(null)` wasn't working before, I may be missing some previous mistake, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase initially applies transactions client-side, to improve concurrency. If that decision does not meet your use-case, you can pass an additional argument to the `transaction` method that tells it to by-pass the local apply.

See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html

> **applyLocally** Boolean Optional
>
> By default, events are raised each time the transaction update function runs. So if it is run multiple times, you may see intermediate states. You can set this to false to suppress these intermediate states and instead wait until the transaction has completed before events are raised.